# How can I check if a user reacted to the bot's message and then send a message if he didn't or if he did ( all in DM's )

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I'm not too sure how I would do this. I'm trying to make it so if someone says a command (already finished this part), the bot would send that member a DM saying something like this, "please react with any emoji to continue, (also finished this part), so know I have to make it check if the member reacted or if he didn't (with a time limit of 12 seconds).

Here's what I've already got:

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
    let args = message.content.slice(PREFIX.length).split(" ");
    switch (args[0]) {
        case "SpamDM":
            message.react('✔️');
            const SpamEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setTitle("Command: DMTest ")
                .setDescription("Please go to DM's");
            message.channel.send(SpamEmbed);
            message.author.send("Please react with any message to continue.");
            break;
    }
});

bot.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Message#createReactionCollector](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) to do this.

```js
const filter = (reaction, user) => {
    return reaction.emoji.name === '✔️' && user.id === message.author.id;
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 12000 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(`Collected ${reaction.emoji.name} from ${user.tag}`);
    // The user (who sent the command) has now reacted
});
```

The `collect` event will only fire if the person who sent the command has reacted to it, because of the `filter` that has been setup. The time is currently set to 12000ms which is 12 seconds.

There is also an `end` event emitted, which you could use to see if the user did or didn't react to the message, for example:

```js
collector.on('end', collected => {
    console.log(`Collected ${collected.size} items`);
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help.

Comment: Please mark this answer as correct if it has worked for you to help other users find an answer